# Concatenating values in target column

Tags: vba, excel, loops, concatenation

I'm having troubles with a VBA code: There's an Excel sheet (`Sheet1`) that contains two essential columns (last & first name)

[image: name list]

What I am trying to do is, that whenever you add another last and first name to the list, both of them automatically get concatenated in another sheet and form a new list (start position for that list is `Sheet11.Range("AB3")`, on position `AB2` is the list title "Clients").

My code therefore was entered in `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim tmp As Range
For Each tmp In Sheet1.Range("C4:C100")
If tmp.Value <> "" And tmp.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
Sheet11.Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "AB").Value = tmp.Value & " " & tmp.Offset(0, 1).Value
End If
Next tmp

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I enter first & last names while this code is active, the concatenated names are not listed one after another, but the last name in the list replaces the list title in `AB2`.

[image: concatenated name list]

I guess the problem lies somewhere within the loop process, but I can't seem to figure out the logic behind it. I'd be thankful for any suggestions to solve that problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the following instruction

```
Sheet11.Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "AB").Value
```

returns the same cell each time the loop is repeated. You can replace this whole line for example by this:

```
Range("AB" & tmp.Row).Value = tmp.Value & " " & tmp.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro to change the values of cell on the same worksheet, you need to turn off event handling or the value change will trigger a new event and the Worksheet_Change will try to run on top of itself. This also holds true for other worksheets that contain a Worksheet_Change unless you want the change in value to force the event. Similarly, the **Target** can represent more than a single cell (e.g. a paste operation) so you need to deal with the individual cells in the **Intersect**, not the Intersect as a whole.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B:C")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim bc As Range
        For Each bc In Intersect(Target, Columns("B:C"))
            Sheet11.Cells(bc.Row, "AB") = _
              Join(Array(Cells(bc.Row, "B").Value2, Cells(bc.Row, "C").Value2))
        Next bc
    End If
bm_Safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've used the [Join Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as the string concatenation mechanism. While any character can be supplied as a connector in a **Join**, the default is a space.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a faster Change event - you don't need to loop over all rows for every update

This will add new entries and update existing ones:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 And .Row >= 3 And (.Column = 3 Or .Column = 4) Then
            Dim cel As Range
            Set cel = Cells(.Row, 3)
            If Len(cel) > 0 And Len(cel.Offset(0, 1)) > 0 Then
                Worksheets("Sheet11").Range("AB" & .Row) = cel & " " & cel.Offset(0, 1)
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```